# iOS Http Proxy Setting API

Tags: ios, proxy

do have any iOS system API or other methods can modify System Network Http Proxy Setting .
[image]

I have searched only find reading method for Proxy but can not modify

```
NSDictionary *proxySettings = (__bridge NSDictionary *)CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings();

NSArray *proxies = (__bridge NSArray *)CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL(
    (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"],
    (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)proxySettings);

NSDictionary *settings = [proxies objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"host=%@", [settings objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFProxyHostNameKey]);
NSLog(@"port=%@", [settings objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFProxyPortNumberKey]);
NSLog(@"type=%@", [settings objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFProxyTypeKey]);
```

Comment: Your given code exclusively works on macOS development, not for iOS. From what I understand, there are no public APIs that could modify System HTTP Proxy.

Comment: thansk @NghiaTran